# Galaxy S debugging mode: connection error

Tags: eclipse, debugging, galaxy

I connected my device (Galaxy S) to my pc in debug mode and in logcat I have the following error in a loop each second. Any clue of how to get rid of it?

```
    05-09 10:33:03.816: INFO/java.net.Socket(2691): broker.useful-apps.com/62.219.7.92(18182): java.net.ConnectException: broker.useful-apps.com/62.219.7.92:18182 - Connection refused
05-09 10:33:03.826: INFO/java.net.Socket(2691): broker.useful-apps.com/31.25.113.5(18182): java.net.ConnectException: broker.useful-apps.com/31.25.113.5:18182 - Connection refused
05-09 10:33:03.831: INFO/java.net.Socket(2691): broker.useful-apps.com/31.25.113.12(18182): java.net.ConnectException: broker.useful-apps.com/31.25.113.12:18182 - Connection refused
05-09 10:33:03.841: INFO/java.net.Socket(2691): broker.useful-apps.com/62.219.7.66(18182): java.net.ConnectException: broker.useful-apps.com/62.219.7.66:18182 - Connection refused
05-09 10:33:03.846: INFO/java.net.Socket(2691): broker.useful-apps.com/31.25.113.7(18182): java.net.ConnectException: broker.useful-apps.com/31.25.113.7:18182 - Connection refused
05-09 10:33:03.851: INFO/java.net.Socket(2691): broker.useful-apps.com/31.25.113.9(18182): java.net.ConnectException: broker.useful-apps.com/31.25.113.9:18182 - Connection refused
05-09 10:33:03.856: ERROR/fring(2691): Exception:testInternetConnection: java.net.ConnectException: broker.useful-apps.com/31.25.113.4:18182 - Connection refused
05-09 10:33:03.856: WARN/System.err(2691): java.net.ConnectException: broker.useful-apps.com/31.25.113.4:18182 - Connection refused
05-09 10:33:03.861: WARN/System.err(2691):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:255)
05-09 10:33:03.861: WARN/System.err(2691):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:220)
05-09 10:33:03.861: WARN/System.err(2691):     at java.net.Socket.startupSocket(Socket.java:797)
05-09 10:33:03.866: WARN/System.err(2691):     at java.net.Socket.tryAllAddresses(Socket.java:192)
05-09 10:33:03.866: WARN/System.err(2691):     at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:256)
05-09 10:33:03.866: WARN/System.err(2691):     at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:220)
05-09 10:33:03.866: WARN/System.err(2691):     at com.fring.comm.a.a(InternetConnectionTester.java:37)
05-09 10:33:03.871: WARN/System.err(2691):     at com.fring.comm.o.f(FringConnectionManager.java:64)
05-09 10:33:03.871: WARN/System.err(2691):     at com.fring.comm.ae.run(FringConnectionManager.java:659)
05-09 10:33:03.876: WARN/System.err(2691): java.io.IOException: Testing internet connection failed!
05-09 10:33:03.876: WARN/System.err(2691):     at com.fring.comm.o.f(FringConnectionManager.java:64)
05-09 10:33:03.876: WARN/System.err(2691):     at com.fring.comm.ae.run(FringConnectionManager.java:659)
```

Comment: Ok, just removed fring app from my device. Couldn't find any smart solution.